# ReportViewer height issue in IE11 when document mode is Edge

Tags: asp.net, html, css, reporting, reportviewer

I have report viewer in my asp.net page. I want report viewer to be visible in full page. I tried to specify height (100%) but it doesn’t work, I have also specify the AsyncRendering="False"

I have also tried SizeToReportContent="true”, but when I apply this property to report viewer it sets initially the search parameters has some random height and width. Is there any other way to resolve this issue?

Especially I want this to be fixed in IE11 with all Document Mode (Edge, etc…)

Answer (score 0):

try out the `ZoomMode="FullPage"`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the report viewer to full page code given below :

Place this code in the header part

        /* For Report Viewer Full Page Rendering*/

```
    div#content { width: 100%; }
    div#content span div table { width: 100%; }
    div#content span div table tr { width: 100% !important; }
    div#content span div table tr:nth-child(2) { width: 100% !important; }
    div#content span div table td[id*='oReportCell'] table  { width: 100% !important; }
```

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: And this code in the body part 

<div id="content">
                <asp:Panel ID="pnk" runat="server" ScrollBars="Auto">
                    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Style="min-height: 450px; min-width: 980px;"
                        ZoomMode="PageWidth" ShowBackButton="true" SizeToReportContent="True" Font-Size="8pt">
                    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
                </asp:Panel>
</div>